# Analogue of fetch for Mercurial? How to see a new branch from IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, repository, branch

If a branch is created in the repository (Git or Mercurial), I still don't see it in the IntelliJIdea. If the CVS is Git, I have to issue `fetch` command for to see a new branches.

But for Mercurial I don't see neither `fetch`, nor something similar. How can I make that new branch visible for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you mean a branch created on a remote server. 
It is not IntelliJ specific, you need to get information into your local repository first (this is what you actually do calling pull in Tortoise)

But you don't need to use Tortoise, you can pull from IDEA using `VCS - Mercurial - Pull`